# What is the difference between those connection strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to use the visual studio - asp.net MVC login module, after some search I found that I only need to change the connection string to the SQL Server and it will create the database and the tables for me after Registration. the default connection string in the Web.config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-FullTest-20161219090404.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-FullTest-20161219090404;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I don't understand that connection string and don't know what to change about it, also I know that when I connect to SQL Server, my connection string always looks like that:

```
<add name="ProjectNameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ProjectNameModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ProjectNameModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ProjectNameModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=DatabaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

So what is the difference between those connection strings? and please what I need to change in the connection string to work properly. I've tried:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FullTestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.FullTestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.FullTestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=FullTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And it is not Working. I need to understand the connection strings how they work properly.

Thanks

Comment: First one is a regular connection string to Local DB. Second one is old-style Entity Framework connection string (intended for `ObjectContext` API). Why do you compare them and what is "not working"? Could you describe your problem details?

Comment: sorry for that. I didn't knew that the second one is an old style Entity Framework connection string. My problem simply is I want to add to my project the already implemented login module of MVC, that create its tables and database. I need to conenct it to the SQL server instsead to the Local DB. How to achieve that simply?

Comment: Does this module use EF? What exactly doesn't work? Any exceptions? The third connection string looks OK.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's exactly the problem, The project I've created now is an ready MVC Template. All I've done is creating a new project, and instead of the second connection string, I need to change it to connect to the database in the SQL server. EF is not required at all.

Comment: If so, just use connection string part between `provider connection string=&quot;` and `;App=EntityFramework&quot;` in third sample.